# Android: setOnClickListener not triggering on every other tap

Tags: android, button, click

I have a button with a setOnClickListener event handler. When I tap on the button, the event handler does not trigger. When I tap on it again, it triggers. If I then tap on it again, it doesn't trigger. Tap on it once more and it triggers. What can be causing this alternating triggering? Here is my code along with the UI markup:

```
Button btnDownload = (Button) this.viewSpecGeneral.findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);

btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
  }
}
```

XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDownload"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/lblFileSize"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient_green"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:minWidth="110dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/lbl_Download"
    android:textColor="#486b3f"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: To be clear: since your `onClick()` method is empty here, how do you know it skips every other tap?

Comment: put any log inside onClick() method

Comment: I just removed both the focusable and focusableInTouchMode and the problem goes away.

Comment: I had a hunch about that, be wary of `focusableInTouchMode` it sometimes does odd things... Anyway, please post this as an answer or delete the question, so this doesn't remain "unsolved".

Answer (score 1):

I just removed both the focusable and focusableInTouchMode and the problem goes away.